# How to setup variable in nodejs typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

How come running this on postman
localhost:3000/api/watson/get-test

it gives error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'myTest' of undefined

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';

export class IbmWatsonRouter {
  router: Router;
  mytest: any;

  /**
   * Initialize the Router
   */
  constructor() {
    this.mytest = new Service();
    this.router = Router();
    this.init();   

  }

  /**
   * Get
   */
  public getTest(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {            
    res.send(this.mytest.getSomething());    
  }

  /**
   * POST Analyze-Text.
   */
  public analyzeText(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    this.mytest.setSomething('aaaa');
    res.send('successfully analyze text');    
  }

  /**
   * Take each handler, and attach to one of the Express.Router's
   * endpoints.
   */
  init() {
    this.router.get('/get-test', this.getTest);
    this.router.post('/analyze-text', this.analyzeText);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate router, service and controller. Also, any function in a controller should be static.

**Router**

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import {IbmWatsonController} from './controllers/ibmwatson';
export const router = Router();
router.get('/get-test', IbmWatsonController.getTest);
router.post('/analyze-text', IbmWatsonController.analyzeText);
```

**Controller**

```
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {Service} from '../services/service';
const serviceInstance = new Service();
export class IbmWatsonController {
  public static getTest(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {            
    res.send(serviceInstance.example);    
  }

  public static analyzeText(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)   {
    serviceInstance.example = 'aaaa';
    res.send('successfully analyze text');    
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
//@todo: rewrite with stateless solution
export class Service {
   privat mytest = 'aaaaa';
   get example(): string {
      return mytest;
   }
   set example(val: string): string {
      this.mytest = val;
   }    
}
```

Comment: well my goal is actually for that mytest variable to be a new class. So I can shared it between getTest and analyzeText. if I put it as const I would not be able to change it right?

I'm looking something like. mytest = newClass();

then, analyzeText will be something like mytest.setvariable('aaa');
and getTest will be something like mytest.getVariable() -> which will return 'aaa'

Comment: With this approach, your REST app will not be stateless. After restart you will lose the value. Also, you can't make cluster of your app. Could you use the file, Redis or any DB for storing the value?

Comment: I'm fine with losing value after restart. My main thing right now is to make sure I dont have to renew the service for every api call

Comment: Okey. I fixed by adding service. Please, use SOLID principles in typescript.
In the service, I used getter/setter and instance. But you can use static getter/setter or scoped variable.

Comment: It works. Although setting it up as const feels not right. What is the "best practice of this?"

Comment: Objects are held by reference in JavaScript, not by value. `const` for an object means that the reference is immutable. So you will can't change the reference, but can change object field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with this line:

```
this.router.get('/get-test', this.getTest);
```

`this.getTest` is an unbound function reference. It has no context.

Try replacing it with:

```
this.router.get('/get-test', () => this.getTest);
```

Comment: it does not work. I dont think it's anything to do with the router

Answer (score 0):

You need to **bind** the context. 
Try with something like this:

```
this.router.get('/get-test', this.getTest.bind(this));
```

The complete example:

```js
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import express from 'express';

class Service {
    getSomething() {
        return 'Hola';
    }
}

class IbmWatsonRouter {
  router = null;
  mytest = null;
  app = null;

  /**
   * Initialize the Router
   */
  constructor() {
    this.mytest = new Service();
    this.router = Router();
    this.init();   

  }

  /**
   * Get
   */
  getTest(req, res, next) {            
      //res.send('ok');
    res.send(this.mytest.getSomething());    
  }

  /**
   * POST Analyze-Text.
   */
  analyzeText(req, res, next) {
    this.mytest.setSomething('aaaa');
    res.send('successfully analyze text');    
  }

  /**
   * Take each handler, and attach to one of the Express.Router's
   * endpoints.
   */
  init() {
    this.router.get('/get-test', this.getTest.bind(this));
    this.router.post('/analyze-text', this.analyzeText);
    this.app = express();
    this.app.use(this.router);
    this.app.listen(5200, () => {
        console.log('App listening on 5200');
        
    });    
  }

}

const r = new IbmWatsonRouter;
```